# Did any of Aragorn's ancestors ever try to reclaim the crown of Gondor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Two part question:

**Did any of Aragorn's ancestors try to reclaim the throne of Gondor?**
If so, why did they fail? (I assume they did)

**If not, why not?**
Did they not know about their heritage, not qualify somehow, were they too busy, or did they all just decide they didn't want to?